# Fetching another user's data based on their uid

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to impliment the following form the docs:

`UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(uid);`

However, it doesn't seem to be recognised, nor is there an option to import anything to be able to use it.

I have the following in my build file:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

Comment: There is no getUser method on FirebaseAuth.  What exactly are you looking at that suggests there is one?

Comment: @DougStevenson he is using the admin java sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data ,then click on the java tab

Comment: @PeterHaddad The Admin SDK is not meant for use in Android apps (and it's not listed in the dependencies in as shown).

Comment: @PeterHaddad, I would argue that this should not be duped, as the line I used, which is from the docs,is not referenced in the other question. Anyone searching on that line would not be taken there, as I was not. IOW, the answer is the same, but the questions not. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @DougStevenson, why is this code given in the docs if it is, if I'm understanding correctly, redundant?

Comment: What exactly are you looking at that suggests that you can run this code from an Android app?

Comment: @DougStevenson, Frank has clarified for me, in the below answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question is from the Firebase Admin SDK, which is an SDK meant for use in environments you control (e.g. a server or your development laptop).

The build.gradle fragments you shared are for an Android app. The Firebase Admin SDK is not compatible with Android apps.

There is no way to get the user profile for another user in the Android SDK. If there was, anyone could reverse engineer your Android app, and look up information for any of your users.

What you could do is use the Admin SDK to expose an endpoint that your Android app can call. But you'd need your own way of setting up a Java endpoint for that, or alternatively use the Admin SDK for Node.js and serve it from Cloud Functions. In either of those cases, be aware that an unprotected endpoint allowing such a lookup will probably be seen as a breach of trust by you users.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. My objective was to increase the speed of user image look ups by directly accessing their user URI, as opposed to moving the image file to Storage and getting it from there, which seems to be slower. I'll fall back to that approach until something better presents itself. Do you perhaps know of a better approach to keep user images on a chat list current?

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant just get all user data unless you know what you are doing .

STEP one create a JSON ARRAY of name users that contain all the ids of the users that you add in .

STEP two call users in datasnapshot get all of their ids and if you want you can save the users data within those uid in real time database .

**YOU CANNOT GET ALL THE USERS INFO JUST FROM YOUR USERS AND NO REFRENCE IN REAL TIME DB**